# Playing different sounds on different buttons

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm making drumpad and i need to make buttons have different sounds when clicked 
this is my code and this works for one button only

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick1)
        button1.setOnClickListener{
            mediaPlayer?.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Kotlin but something similar to this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener{
    var mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick1)
    mediaPlayer1?.start()
}

button2.setOnClickListener{
    var mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick2)
    mediaPlayer2?.start()
}
```